# Kernel of $\text{Res}_p$ on a Riemann surface

Tags: complex-geometry, differential-forms, riemann-surfaces, meromorphic-functions

Let $X$ be a Riemann surface and let $p\in X$. Let:
$$\text{Res}_p:\Omega^1_{\text{mero}}(X)\to \mathbb{C}$$
be the residue at $p$ operator defined on meromorphic $1$-forms. Clearly holomorphic $1$-forms are in the kernel of this operator. By Stokes theorem also differentials of meromorphic functions are in the kernel.

Is this a complete description of the kernel?

In other words , does the following equality hold?

$$\text{ker}(\text{Res}_p)=\Omega^1(X)+d\mathscr{M}(X)$$

Comment: You do not mean holomorphic functions. Think about a Laurent expansion centered at $p$ of a meromorphic $1$-form. Does it prove/confirm what you're asking?

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you, I meant holomorphic $1$-forms. But are all of the Laurent expansion convergent to a meromorphic function?

Comment: If you meant locally holomorphic/meromorphic then yes, if you meant globally holomorphic/meromorphic then no, as your proposed kernel doesn't depend on $p$.

Comment: The interesting question is to caracterize $\bigcap_{p\in X} \ker(Res_p)$

Comment: @reuns By locally meromorphic you mean that it's holomorphic in a neighboorhood of $p$ (except in $p$ that may be a pole)?

Comment: @reuns Now I'm curious! What's that intersection?

Comment: Just to clarify: Are you assuming $X$ is compact?

Comment: To add to @reuns’s point, no one says the residues at *other* poles have to be $0$. What kind of expression for the kernel are you expecting? A characterization, perhaps, in terms of integration?

Comment: @TedShifrin By reading reun's comments I understood that $\ker(Res_p)$ is the sum of locally holomorphic forms and differentials of locally meromorphic functions. Now I'd like to know if that intersection is actually the sum $\Omega^1(X)+d\mathscr{M}(X)$. I'm not assuming $X$ compact, but if there is some cool result in the compact case I'd like to know about it!